# Jquery finding and replacing last value in a list

Tags: jquery

I have a variable in a list that looks something like this (it's a link url

```
var SubmitUrl = "78EDAC7/CustomerAccountID/27/OrderObjectID/254756/Quantity/1"
OR
var SubmitUrl = "78EDAC7/CustomerAccountID/27/OrderObjectID/254756/Quantity/3"
OR
var SubmitUrl = "78EDAC7/CustomerAccountID/27/OrderObjectID/254756/Quantity/200320"
```

What I want to do is grab the value after Quantity/ and replace it when someone changes the value in the qty_1 input box.

The value after Quantity/ will be the last one in the list.

`$(#custom)` is ID for the link they click and I'm updating the `submitUrl` before they take off with the updated quantity "if" there is an updated quantity

```
$('#custom').click(function(e){
... update submitUrl ....
});
```

I just don't know how to find that placeholder and then replace it with the value from the input box (if they changed the value) ... they could change it at any time way before they click or just before they click the button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regular expressions are your friend for matching/replacing sequences of  text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex version:

```
 SubmitUrl = SubmitUrl.replace(/[^\/]+$/, newId);
```

Replaces the last part of SubmitUrl with the contents of newId.

Comment: Thanks - that did it for me perfectly short and simple

Answer (score 0):

Addition to davidkonrad, to change the placeholder,

```
$("yourfield").attr("placeholder",test[test.length-1]);
```